# How can I export my output to excel?

Tags: export, excel

so after you all helped me a lot, I got now this code:

```
R[n_, b_, l_, m_, d_, p_] := 
 1/2 l (b - (4 b)/(1 + n) + 2 (l/(m n p))^(1/(-1 + p)))
F[l_, m_, n_, b_, d_, p_] := -d + (b l)/(n + n^2) - 
  m ((l/(m n p))^(1/(-1 + p)))^p
HR[n_, b_, l_, m_, d_, p_] := 
 l/(m p (p - 1)) (n m p/l)^((p - 2)/(p - 1))

Table[ToString /@ {ArgMax[{R[n, b, l, m, d, p], n >= 2, 
     HR[n, b, l, m, d, p] < b, F[l, m, n, b, d, p] >= 0}, 
    n ∈ Integers], 
   MaxValue[{R[n, b, l, m, d, p], n >= 2, F[l, m, n, b, d, p] >= 0, 
     HR[n, b, l, m, d, p] < b}, n ∈ Integers]}, {b, (11/
    10), (11/10)}, {l, 61/10, 61/10}, {m, 61/10, 61/10}, {d, 1/10, 1/10}, {p, 12/10, 12/10}]
```

which gives me this outcome {{{{{{"7", "10962680209
      -----------
      6534561600"}}}}}}

How do i transport these results into excel, so that both are shown in numbers and in different fields of the matrix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because yet again a post of this user does not show any effort whatsoever, doesn't include an actual question and comes with no minimal working example but a mess of unreadable code instead.

Comment: The `Table` functions doesn't make sense as used here. For all loop variables, the start and end values are the same. The `ToString` does not make sense to me either. Anyway, have you studied `Export` and the manual sections on XLS or XLSX?

Comment: Enter your keyword "excel" into the search box of documentation window and explore the links you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just google "Mathematica Export XLS", you will get hundreds if not thousands suggestions or do this

[image]

or use this,

```
Export["C:/tcdata/myfile.xls", data]
```

Comment: @sjoerd Thx for pointing out the tostring problem to me

Comment: @Andreas You are always welcome. Don't be discourage ask freely.